# How to refresh custom jtable model that extends AbstractTableModel to replace values when a button is clicked?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable

How can I refresh the JTable so that it displays the new values that I will pass in it when a button is clicked

Here's my custom JTable Mode:

```
static class MyModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private final String[] columnNames = {"Last Name", "First Name", "Email Address", "Address", "Age",
            "Residence Type", "District Number", "Gender"};
    private ArrayList<String[]> Data = new ArrayList<>();

    public void AddCSVData(ArrayList<String[]> DataIn) {

        ArrayList<String[]> stringList = DataIn;
        this.Data = stringList;
        this.fireTableDataChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;// length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return Data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columnNames[col];
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        return Data.get(row)[col];
    }

    public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
        return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        String[][] cells = null;
        cells[rowIndex][columnIndex] = (String) aValue;
        fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
    }
}
```

and here's the button that when clicked, the values in the jtable are supposed to be updated:

```
ascendingButton = new JButton("Ascending");
    ascendingButton.setBounds(60, 120, 120, 30);
    sidePane.add(ascendingButton);
    ascendingButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            MyProgramUtility hehe = new MyProgramUtility();
            String path = "src\\res\\data.csv";

            try {
                ArrayList<Citizen> array = MyProgramUtility.printNameAscending(MyProgramUtility.readCSV(path), path);


                List<String> strings = array.stream()
                   .map(object -> Objects.toString(object, null))
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());

                ArrayList<String[]> array1 = new ArrayList<>();
                for (String g : strings) {
                    OneRow = g.split(",(?=([^\\\"]*\\\"[^\\\"]*\\\")*[^\\\"]*$)");
                    Rs.add(OneRow);
                }

                spreadSheet = new JTable(new MyModel());
                spreadSheet.setModel(NewModel);
                ArrayList<String[]> Rs2 = Rs;
                NewModel.AddCSVData(Rs2);
                System.out.println("Rows: " + NewModel.getRowCount());
                System.out.println("Cols: " + NewModel.getColumnCount());

            } catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
                fileNotFoundException.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

    });
    descendingButton = new JButton("Descending");
    descendingButton.setBounds(200, 120, 120, 30);
    sidePane.add(descendingButton);
    descendingButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String path = "src\\res\\data.csv";

            try {
                ArrayList<Citizen> array = MyProgramUtility.printNameDescending(MyProgramUtility.readCSV(path), path);


                List<String> strings = array.stream()
                        .map(object -> Objects.toString(object, null))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());

                ArrayList<String[]> array1 = new ArrayList<>();
                for (String g : strings) {
                    OneRow = g.split(",(?=([^\\\"]*\\\"[^\\\"]*\\\")*[^\\\"]*$)");
                    Rs.add(OneRow);
                }

                ArrayList<String[]> Rs2 = Rs;
                NewModel.AddCSVData(Rs2);
                System.out.println("Rows: " + NewModel.getRowCount());
                System.out.println("Cols: " + NewModel.getColumnCount());

            } catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
                fileNotFoundException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Here's a picture of the GUI design.

[image: Program User Interface]

I tried the code above and it only prints out the values in the terminal. It doesn't update the JTable as I planned it to. Your help would be deeply appreciated.

[image: Terminal Output]

Comment: What is NewModel? If it's the model of the displayed JTable the view is updated as soon as you call fireTableDataChanged(), the creation of a new JTable and a new TableModel is useless.

Comment: @Rocco I have removed the line but it still does not update the table.

Comment: You didn't answer, I'll clarify my question: what is NewModel? Where is declared? How it's used? The right way to use a JTable is: 1. create TableModel, 2. Create Table using the tablemodel, 3. Insert table into a scroll pane, stop. All changes must go through the table model. See tutorial [How to use tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: Ohh okay, sorry for that. The NewModel is declared in the main class (MyProgram). It is added as the table model of the JTable (spreadsheet) and then spreadsheet is added to a scrollpane. What my problem is I wanted to update the values in the jtable when a user clicks a button or something in the dropdown list. I tried adding the sorted data into the NewModel (i.e. spreadsheet = new JTable (new MyModel)) but it doe not go as I planned it to be.

Comment: Then it should work, I only noted that you are using an Rs arrayList, if this is the list that backs up your model, then it's never cleared, so new lines are added to the model and does not replace existing ones. For better answer post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), otherwise we can just guess what the problem is.